# Java 3d game random pixels not appearing

Tags: java

I have been watching tutorials on how to make a 3D game in Java using Eclipse. I have copied all the code word for word and am not getting the same result and it is very frustrating. At the moment all I am trying to do is create a small square of randomly generated pixels and all I'm getting is a blank window. This is the code and classes I am using.

Class1 = Display

```
package com.mime.testgame2;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.DataBufferInt;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import com.mime.testgame2.graphics.Render;
import com.mime.testgame2.graphics.Screen;

public class Display extends Canvas implements Runnable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static final int width = 800;
    public static final int height = 600;
    public static String title = "3D Game Pre-Alpha 0.0.1";

    private Thread thread;
    private boolean running = false;
    private Render render;
    private Screen screen;
    private BufferedImage img;
    private int[] pixels;

    public Display() {
        screen = new Screen(width, height);
        img = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        pixels = ((DataBufferInt) img.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
    }

    private void start() {
        if (running)
            return;
        running = true;
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }

    private void stop() {
        if(!running) return;
        running = false;
        try {
            thread.join();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        while (running) {
            tick();
        render();


        }

    }

    private void tick() {

    }

    private void render() {
        BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
        if (bs == null) {
            createBufferStrategy(3);
            return;
        }

            screen.render();


        for (int i = 0; i < width * height; i++) {
            pixels[i] = screen.pixels[i];
        }

        Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height, null);
        g.dispose();
        bs.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Display game = new Display();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(game);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(width, height);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setTitle(title);

    }

}
```

Class2 = Render

```
package com.mime.testgame2.graphics;

public class Render {
public final int Width;
    public final int Height;
    public final int[] pixels;

    public Render(int Width, int Height) {
        this.Width = Width;
        this.Height = Height;
        pixels = new int[Width * Height];
    }
    public void draw(Render render, int xOffset, int yOffset) {
        for(int y = 0; y < render.Height; y++) {
            int yPix = y + yOffset;
            for(int x = 0; x < render.Width; x++) {
                int xPix = x + xOffset;

                pixels[xPix + yPix * Width] = render.pixels[x + y * rend            er.Width];
                }
            }
    }

}
```

Class3 = Screen

```
package com.mime.testgame2.graphics;

import java.util.Random;

public class Screen extends Render {

    private Render test;

    public Screen(int Width, int Height) {
        super(Width, Height);
        Random random = new Random();
        test = new Render(256, 256);
        for (int i = 0; i < 256 * 256; i++) {
            test.pixels[i] = random.nextInt();
        }

    }

    public void render() {
        draw(test, 0, 0);
    }

}
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive. You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, by tracing the progress of your program, and comparing it to what you expect to happen. As soon as the two diverge, then you've found your problem. (And then if necessary, you should construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).)

Comment: I tried the debugger and it didn't show any errors. Then I tried the print statements and it seems the problem is somewhere in the display class between 'private void start()' and the end of 'public void render()'. Something I have not mentioned that I should have. I have no experience with java at the moment. That is why I can't find the error.